# If $I,J$ are two integrals , Then $101I+eJ = $ is

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If

\begin{align*}
I &= \int^{e}_{1}(1+x)(x+\ln x)^{100}\,dx,\\
J &= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\arcsin(1/e)}(1+e\sin x+\ln \sin x)^{101}\cos x\,dx.
\end{align*}

Then $101I+eJ = \ ?$

Attempt: Put $\sin x= t$ and $\cos dx = dt.$

So $$J=-\int^{1}_{e^{-1}}(1+et+\ln t)\,dt.$$

Could some help me how I relate it to $I,$ thanks.

Comment: @  kingW3 i have edited it.

Comment: it is$$\approx 1.23163\cdot 10^{144}$$

Comment: I suggest you to put $t=e\sin x$ instead.

Comment: As $\dfrac{d(x+\ln x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1+x}x,$

$$T_m=\int(1+x)(x+\ln x)^m\ dx=\int x\left(\dfrac{1+x}x\cdot(x+\ln x)^m\right)dx$$

$$=x\int\left(\dfrac{1+x}x\cdot(x+\ln x)^m\right)dx-\int\left[\dfrac{dx}{dx}\int\left(\dfrac{1+x}x\cdot(x+\ln x)^m\right)dx\right]dx$$

$$=\dfrac{(x+\ln x)^{m+1}}{m+1}-\dfrac1{m+1}\int(x+\ln x)^{m+1}dx$$

$$\implies\dfrac{T_{m+1}}{m+1}=\dfrac{(x+\ln x)^{m+1}}{m+1}-T_m$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have $\color{red}{101}I$ it should hint you to consider $((x+\ln x)^{101})'=101(x+\ln x)^{101}(1+\frac{1}{x})$ so we have that
$$101I=\int_1^ex((x+\ln x)^{101})'=x(x+\ln x)^{101}|_1^e-\int_1^e(x+\ln x)^{101}dx$$
Now for $J$ you have made a mistake.  $$J=\int_{e^{-1}}^1(1+et+\ln t)^{101}$$
Now can you think what substitution you  can make for $J$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about what substitutions on your $I$-integral would give you the bounds you have on your $J$-integral.